# Easier navigation through filesystem in linux shell (cli)

Tags: linux, shell, command-line-interface, ls, cd

I often find myself taking a lot of time to navigate through my filesystem when using the linux shell. This generally occurs because the autocompletion of bash only works if you provide the start of the file/dirname. What I often end up in is a lot of 'ls' with 'grep' commands, finally doing a 'cd'.

When you use a GUI based filebrowser (like Nautilus) you can type any part of a file/dirname and it will have matches that it jumps to directly. This makes it a lot easier and faster to navigate.

I wonder if anybody knows any great tools that helps with this problem. I know of the existence of Midnight Commander, though I never really used it for real and I couldn't figure out a direct solution for my problem the first couple of times I tried it. Also it seems not suitable because I want to have my shell's current working directory to be changed so I can do stuff there, instead of being stuck in an external program like Midnight Commander.

Comment: Sounds like you're structuring files wrong, like maybe putting too many in one folder.  Also, maybe *find* will be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Try autojmp

https://github.com/joelthelion/autojump

And following article provides another solution

http://jeroenjanssens.com/2013/08/16/quickly-navigate-your-filesystem-from-the-command-line.html

Comment: Though it's not my desired solution, I must say i like the article from Jeroen Janssens, thanks for that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can first use the autocd or autopushd in zsh. You would just have to type the directory you want to go to, without the hassle of typing cd or pushd everytime. 
You also have the globing possibility. For example, if I got those file in a directory:

```
1-a.tar
1-b.tar
c.tar
```

I can just type

```
*a.tar
```

without caring about the beginning of the file.

As a last solution you can always use an alias to the find command with a personalized option.